# What is the cause of different TCL script behaviour when redirecting the output to a file under Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, tcl

When calling script as

```
tclsh ./TestDriver.tcl TestList
```

the tcl script stops after one (?) line. But when called with output redirected to a file

```
tclsh ./TestDriver.tcl TestList >bar.out
```

it runs smoothly. 
Any ideas what might be the cause of such behavior ?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? For example, can you show the Tcl script up to the point that it stalls / exits?

Comment: I will run more tests to try to reproduce this problem on simple scripts, and write more when I'll have more results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all Tcl scripts work identically when their output is directed to a terminal or to a file. While there is a [`tcl_interactive`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/UserCmd/tclsh.htm#M10) variable that things could be keyed off, it doesn't come into play when you're supplying the script as an argument. The other base-line difference is that `stdout` will have different [buffering](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/fconfigure.htm#M6) by default; you can change that to be defined with:

```
fconfigure stdout -buffering none ;# Or “line” or “full”
```

However, I would expect the differences there to make things (very marginally) less likely to work in the case of being redirected to a file. Whatever is going on (and I bet it either involves running subprocesses or the use of extension packages) I can't guess it on the basis of the evidence provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the tcl program is calling an istty function, and changing it's behavior depending on if it thinks it's writing to terminal.  Possibly, it's attempting to format the output, and a wide terminal is causing it to fail.